# What I can get if I only use libvirt for kvm/qemu?

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, kvm, libvirt

I think the major feature of libvirt is abstract the different target, but if I only use kvm/qemu, what I can get from libvirt ?

Comment: I'm hard-pressed whether this is "too broad" or "opinion-based". What is or isn't a valuable feature is exceedingly subjective and dependent on one's local set of use cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is quite a large set of benefits of libvirt, besides just hypervisor abstraction. Rather than list them all here, check out the blog post I wrote about this a few years back.

https://www.berrange.com/posts/2011/06/07/what-benefits-does-libvirt-offer-to-developers-targetting-qemukvm/

Everything listed there is still relevant today, and we've added some benefits since then, in particular running QEMU in separate mount namespace to isolate QEMU from the host /dev nodes.

Answer (score 0):

the use of this abstraction layer becomes very handy when you start to script or automate KVM deplyments but ...

The main added value in the KVM QEMU setup is the Live Migation of a Virtual Machine to an ohter Hardware with Hypervisor.

Comment: ...which can be done with or without libvirt, so I'm not sure how I see it as a defensible value-add.